# linked destroy with memset

Tags: c, list

I have found this in a book I bought, which is about algorithms.

I would like to know if it’s allowed through the C99 standard
to destroy linked lists like this or are there any conventions that say that this is stupid?

```
void list_destroy(List *list) {
   void *data;
   while (list_size(list) > 0) {
       if (list_rem_next(list, NULL, (void **)&data) == 0 && list->destroy != NULL) {
           list->destroy(data);
       }
   }
   memset(list, 0, sizeof(List));
   return;
}
```

Why does this work? I learned to free allocated memory with free()?

Comment: What exactly throws you off? `memset` or `list->destroy` or something else?

Comment: You've not shown how the `List` structure is defined.  Zeroing the structure may be legitimate.  It marks it as unusable until it is initialized again..  Maybe this code cannot tell whether the list structure it was given was allocated (and hence is freeable) or not.  Without a good deal more context, it is not possible to be definitive. It is unusual; it is not automatically wrong.

Comment: `memset` doesn’t free allocated memory, it writes over it with a value (zeroes in this case). The other functions called by `list_destroy` may `free` some internal storage, but at the end of this function, `list` will still be a valid pointer, but all the fields of the structure will contain zeroes. What is this function documented as doing?

Comment: @BenediktGruber: you have erased data by memset but you have not freed it. Memory is still allocated

Answer (score 2):

I’m not exactly sure what throws you off, so let’s discuss that code.

```
while (list_size(list) > 0)
```

While there are items in the list we repeat the following block. Doesn’t look unusual to me. So let’s proceed.

```
if (list_rem_next(list, NULL, (void **)&data) == 0 && list->destroy != NULL) {
```

Ok, a function `list_rem_next` is called. I can only guess what it does, but likely it removes some element from the list and store the *data* of this removed element into the `data` variable.

Next we check whether `list->destroy` is not null. Obviously that’s a function pointer which can free-up the data structure. (So if the items in the list were malloc’d this would point to `free`)

```
list->destroy(data);
```

If this is a valid pointer execute the function and pass the *data* to destroy.

```
memset(list, 0, sizeof(List));
```

Finally the *list* structure gets zeroed. A bit strange, but why not. This simply writes 0 from `list` to as many bytes as specified by the 3rd argument.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the `list->destroy` function is doing the "free".

In a perfectly constructed program there would be no reason zero-out memory that you are no longer using.  But you will sometimes see code like this:

```
memset(list, 0, sizeof(List));
```

or even something like this:

```
memset(list, 0x53, sizeof(List));      /* or some other "curious" value */
```

as a way to catch malformed programs which try to access memory after it is freed.  The idea being that the zeros (or weird values) are more likely to cause the program to die as soon as the previously-freed memory is accessed than if it had "good data" still there (kind of a primitive "booby trap").